# Monitor and speaker setup for Playstation 3

Tags: audio, display, external-display, speakers, ps3

I have ordered a PS3 super slim 500GB console, and I plan on connecting it to my PC's monitor and speakers.

The monitor I have is the [Acer S221HQBD](http://www.acerdirect.co.uk/Acer_S221HQLbd_Super_Slim_LED_Monitor_21.5_inch_ET.WS1HE.008/version.asp), which does not have an HDMI port.  So I would imagine that I could connect the PS3 to it using an HDMI to DVI connector.

As for the speakers, I'm not sure what converters or cables I would need to buy - could anyone kindly advise? My speaker/subwoofer setup is the [Logitech S220](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RQSGYO) 2.1 Speaker System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, good question.

heres an [unboxing of your ps3 super slim](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqAi8GXRKmI) you can see it comes with a ps3 input to RCA Male (RED, White (audio) and Yellow (video). We are going to need those Red and White inputs to make this work.

Example:

[image]

This audio adapter : 3.5mm Stereo Female to 2 RCA Female Audio Cable Example:[image]

Which connect to your speakers using a double sided 3.5mm Stereo Male to Male Audio plug. Or from what I see on your speakers the 3.5mm Audio just comes out the back of the speakers. So you should be fine without this cable.

[image]

As you said before this has to be done because DVI does not transmit audio like HDMI does, so this work around is required. This is a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6uF7hYSA8Q) of a person specifically doing what you're doing but i think his audio is powered by usb.

Comment: I have not purchased the cables yet, however I have read stories online of people who tried a similar setup of connecting the PS3 to the monitor through an HDMI to DVI converter, and they have reported black and white screens, rather than colour. Are you certain that I will be able to do this with my monitor?